# Google Spreadsheet Script - Dynamically change cell content based off currently selected cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I recently started messing around with google script for spreadsheets and I was wondering if there is a way to change a cells value based on the currently selected cell? For example, if the cell displaying the row number is in A1 and the user highlights B8, A1 would display '8'. Is that even possible?

Flipping through the google apps-script spreadsheet services page and I noticed a class called .getActiveCell and I'm assuming that would be a key part but I'm kind of lost. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This small code snipet does partially what you need but is unable to detect a simple cell selection, it fires only when the content of a cell is modified.

```
function onEdit(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var cell = ss.getActiveCell();
  ss.getRange('A1').setValue(cell.getA1Notation().replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''));// get A1 notation and rip off any non numeric value to keep only the row number
}
```

As far as I know there is no direct method to get the selection on a simple click or keypress.

Comment: Ah, I see. It sets the value of the cell with the formula based on the last cell edited. I was hoping for something that would update with every new cell selection instead of edit but I'm afraid you are right. I've been looking around the web and it looks like it wouldn't be possible without being incredibly hackish. Your method should be good enough for what I'm trying to do though. Thanks for the help!

P.S. Sorry about not voting you up. I just joined when I asked this question and I apparently need 15 reputation before I can vote people up.

Comment: Accepting is enough :-) thanks. And your right, it would be nice if that was possible... who knows ? maybe some day !

Comment: Yup, maybe some day. Actually, I'll submit a request for that to google. Who knows, maybe the'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

Google Spreadsheet Script allows registering an `onChange(e)` trigger:

[Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

```
function createSpreadsheetEditTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onChange()
      .create();
}
```

I haven't tried if this shoots when a selection is changed.